# See if div contains one or more entered words (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, search, html, contains

I would like to check if any div contains all words entered in an input field. However, currently I am stuck in a situation that as soon as a space is entered, it starts all over, and thus sort of acts like an OR operator instead of an AND operator. Could anyone please push me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="search">aa ab ac ad</div>
<div class="search">ab ba bb bc</div>
<div class="search">bb cc dd ee</div>

<script>
function search(query) {
var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var words = query.toLowerCase().split(" ");

 for (var h = 0, len = divs.length; h < len; ++h) {
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

   if (divs[h].innerHTML.indexOf(words[i]) == -1) {
    divs[h].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
   }
   else {
    divs[h].style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';
   }

  }
 }

}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value);">
```

---

Apparently I was not very clear. My apologies.

What direction do I need to go to make it in Javascript so that it looks for if a div contains AND words[0] AND words[1] AND words[2], etc (so, in any random order)?

Right now when a split takes place, the function starts all over.

Comment: I would definitely consider using regex for this, it seems more appropriate.

Comment: Add `break` after `divs[h].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';` so that once a word is found to be missing, it'll set the color and move on to the next `div`.

Comment: ...also you could put the `divs[h].style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';` after the inner loop. No point in setting the style every time there's a word match. But then you'd need to `continue` the outer loop using a label instead of breaking the inner loop.

Comment: ...or put the `divs[h].style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';` before the inner loop. Then you can skip the `break` or `continue` statement if you want.

Comment: ...also, I'd imagine the user has the option of typing in fewer than `4` words. If so, you should probably check the `.length` of the `query`. If there's not enough words, no point in looping since you know they're not all there.

Comment: @thesystem Thanks and good calls (in particular on the placement). But how do I make it so that if I type "aa ad" it highlights the first div?

Answer (score 0):

Need to also check the length of each query word:

```
<div class="search">aa ab ac ad</div>
<div class="search">ab ba bb bc</div>
<div class="search">bb cc dd ee</div>

<script>
function search(query) {
var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var words = query.toLowerCase().split(" ");

 for (var h = 0, len = divs.length; h < len; ++h) {
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

  if (words[i].length > 0 && divs[h].innerHTML.indexOf(words[i]) >= 0) {
    divs[h].style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';
    break;
   }
   else {
    divs[h].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value);">
```

Comment: Thanks! But now how do I get it to work so that if I search any two, three, four words a div contains (in any order) it highlights that one and doesn't start all over after every word?

Answer (score 0):

Try my code :

**HMTL :**

```
<div class="search">
   <div>aa cC abcc ac ad</div>
   <div>ab ba bb bcc</div>
   <div>bb cc dd ee cc</div>
</div>

<span>Search: </span><input type="text">
```

**CSS :**

```
div{ 
  border:solid 1px #1e2a29; 
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:5px;
  width:auto;
}

.matched{
  background-color:#f8dda9; 
  border:1px solid #edd19b;
  margin:-1px;
  border-radius:2px;
}

input[type="text"]{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('.search > div ').each(function(i, el){
    $(this).data('originalText', $(this).html());
});

$('input').keyup(function(e){
     var _val = $(this).val();
     var _span = '<span class="matched" >$1</span>';
    $('.search  div ').each(function(i, el){            
            var _originalVal = $(el).data('originalText');
            var re = new RegExp('('+_val+')', "ig");
            if(_val.length > 1 && re.test(_originalVal) >=0  ){                    
                $(el).html(_originalVal.replace(re, _span));                    
             }else{
                $(el).html(_originalVal);
            }   
    });
 });
})
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ducwidget/8Mdbz/6/)

Comment: Thanks. This works, though jquery and looking for an exact match of all words in order (in that case, I just wouldn't do a split and look for the exact string inside of a div).