# jQuery addClass from regex match

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to change a block of output from this:

`<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (consectetuer adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt)</div>`

to this:

`<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span class="italics">(consectetuer adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt)</span></div>`

JavaScript:

```
var div = $('div');
var matches = div.match(/\((.*?)\)/);

if (matches) {
  matches.css('color', 'red');
}
```

Basically, use regex to wrap everything in (here) with an addClass. Any ideas?

I feel like this is close:  http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/DjHUt/

Comment: See this post [See if div contains one or more entered words (Javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823631/see-if-div-contains-one-or-more-entered-words-javascript/14824272#14824272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `html` method:

```
$('div').html(function(i, h){
   return h.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, '<span class="italics">$&</span>');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WmCLz/

Comment: Or just use `$&` and remove the capturing group... You also need `g` flag just in case

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, if it should be global, `g` flag is needed. I just used the OP's regex.

Comment: I don't get why you get -1... I have upvoted your answer, since it is a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div = $('div');
div.html(div.text().replace(/\([^)]+\)/g, '<span class="italics">$&</span>'));
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/weJWL/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:  http://jsfiddle.net/cqTq7/2/

Here is my code:

```
var div = $('div'),
    divHTML = div.html();
var match = divHTML.match(/\((.*?)\)/);

divHTML = divHTML.replace(match[0], '<span class="italics">$&</span>');

div.html(divHTML);
```

Note that the `match` function is a function in JavaScript, not jQuery.  Here I also use the JavaScript `replace` function.