# Search for text with javascript inside a div class

Tags: javascript, search

I want to make a script in which I can search for a certain string automatically (no text box or anything, I want to press on a button and it searches for the word "bear" for example inside a) using "document.getElementByClassName"...my C# dev brain started to go for something like "content" or "contains" but I failed terribly...can anyone help me with an example code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you looking to get the search result stored in a variable? Or do you want it displayed on-screen somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823631/see-if-div-contains-one-or-more-entered-words-javascript.

Comment: Basically I want to search for a certain string, and if it is recognized by the script it should do something (e.g display a message box saying "found")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using jquery to easily get the elements by class name and identify those with the search value.  Something like:

```
var searchValue = "bear";

$(".ClassName").each(function(){
  if($(this).html().indexOf(searchValue) > -1){
     //match has been made
  }
});
```

if you are restricted to vanilla javascript, here is an example:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName");
var searchValue = "bear";

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  if(els[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchValue) > -1){
    //match has been made   
  }
}
```

I think what you are really looking for is the comparitor `String.indexOf(SearchValue) > -1`, which will identify if the content of the element is a match for the string you are looking for.  Note that it is case-sensitive.

Comment: Could you post an example of a vanilla javascript example?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `String.indexOf(string)`. [JavaScript indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp).

You can do something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class'); // get the elements

// loop through the elements
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(search) > -1) {
        alert('found'); // popup
    }
}
```